# Isn't TextField's suffix means putting widget at the right hand side of TextField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: The problem is:]

I want to place this CustomDropDownBtn in suffix of **Brought Quantity TextField**. But It is still not placing this Widget in right side of textfield.

```
TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              fillColor: kTextFieldBgColor,
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.none),
              ),
              suffix: this.showSuffixWidget == true ? this.suffixWidget : null,
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.none),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

The suffixWidget in the above code is *[CustomDropDownBtn](https://pastebin.com/itXp9sMP)* Widget.

Tried CustomDropDownBtn to *suffixIcon*, but didn't worked.
Also, I tried

```
suffix: this.showSuffixWidget == true ? Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, this.suffixWidget) : null,
```

But didn't worked.

Is adding padding only the option left?

**Note: removing `this.showSuffixWidget == true ? this.suffixWidget : null,` and adding `Icon(...)` seems to work, but that's not what I want.**

Comment: you want to display dropdown menu inside TextFormField of the left side?

Answer (score 0):

Try using suffixIcon instead of suffix. Or maybe wrap the this.suffixWidget with a sized box of specific width.